# Random Number (rand) does not work outputting an unknown character

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to create a nim game, and I am trying to generate random numbers which is used in the game, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
string player1name,player2name,player1status,player2status,pile1,pile2,pile3;
int main(){
cout<<"What is player 1's name?"<<endl;
getline(cin, player1name);
cout<<"What is player 2's name?"<<endl;
getline(cin, player2name);
pile1 = rand() % 40 + 1;   
cout<<pile1;

return 0;
}
```

It compiles successfully, but its output is like this:

```
What is player 1's name?
Ttyeuo yuwew
What is player 2's name?
Yiefwh HYoaw
?
--------------------------------
Process exited after 15.84 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So the random number generator does not function properly, but I cannot figure out why it happens. Can somebody help me solve this question or suggest a better way to generate random numbers?

Comment: How is the `rand()` not functioning properly? What are you expecting?

Comment: a random number from 1 to 40

Comment: Try `pile1 = std::to_string(rand() % 40 + 1);`

Comment: `<string.h>` is not the correct header for `std::string`.  It is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`.

Comment: Did you look up what happens when you assign an `int` to a `std::string`?

Comment: When posting code, remove the code that doesn't help show the problem. In this case, that's almost all of the code in `main`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not `rand()`.  The issue is that you declared `pile1` as a `std::string`, and thus attempted to assign the return value of `rand()` to `pile1`, which will not work since [rand() returns an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

Either change `pile1` to an `int`, or convert the integer return value to a string:

```
int pile1;
//...
pile1 = rand%40 + 1;
```

[Live Example 1](http://ideone.com/SdskYZ)

or

```
std::string pile1;
//...
pile1 = std::to_string(rand() % 40 + 1);
```

[Live Example 2](http://ideone.com/uj2PJn)

---

Also, the proper `#include` for `std::string` is

`#include <string>`

and not

`#include <string.h>`.

Comment: Possibly worth an edit to add in a note on `srand` and why it's helpful to call it before `rand`.

Comment: @user4581301 When I'm writing in C yeah I still use `rand()` and `srand()` but when I'm using c++ I prefer to use the STL's `<random>` header file with the various engines and distribution types and I have various methods for seeding them such as using a default random engine, a random device, using a high precision clock by using `std::chronos` or even using a `std::seed_seq`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code to this code maybe get best result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout<<"What is player 1's name?"<<endl;
string player1name,player2name,player1status,player2status,pile1,pile2,pile3;
cin >> player1name;
cout<<"What is player 2's name?"<<endl;
cin >> player2name;
pile1 = rand() % 40 + 1;
cout << pile1;
return 0;
}
```